# i am not able to create a new react app i get these errors below i belive i have everythig up to date

Tags: reactjs, installation, yarnpkg

F:\Web-Development>npx create-react-app portfolio-site

Creating a new React app in F:\Web-Development\portfolio-site.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'

warning react-scripts > workbox-webpack-plugin > workbox-build > rollup-plugin-babel@4.4.0: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-babel.

warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

warning react-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-config > jest-environment-jsdom > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

[2/4] Fetching packages...

error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Yarn\Cache\v6\npm-micromatch-3.1.10-70859bc95c9840952f359a068a3fc49f9ecfac23-integrity\node_modules\micromatch\.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected token \u0000 in JSON at position 0".

info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "F:\Web-Development\portfolio-site\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd F:\Web-Development\portfolio-site has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock

****My settings config**.
Yarn version:
1.22.10
Node version:
14.15.2
Npm version :
6.14.9
react also up to date**

Comment: did you try `yarn cache clean`?

Comment: i did it works now thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a cache issue it might be corrupt, can you try the following command it will fix that :

```
yarn cache clean
```